# How to remove training=True from the inbound nodes of a layer in an existing model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Assuming there is a model given as an `h5` file, i.e., I can not change the code building the model's architecture:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(4,))
outputs = BatchNormalization()(inputs, training=True)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.save('model.h5', include_optimizer=False)
```

Now I'd like to remove the `training=True` part, i.e., I want to the `BatchNormalization` as if it was attached to the model without this flag.

My current attempt looks as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('model.h5')

for layer in model.layers:
    for node in layer.inbound_nodes:
        if "training" in node.call_kwargs:
            del node.call_kwargs["training"]

model.predict(np.asarray([[1, 2, 3, 4]]))
```

But the `model.predict` calls fails with the following error (I'm using TensorFlow `2.5.0`):

```
ValueError: Could not pack sequence. Structure had 1 elements, but flat_sequence had 2 elements.  Structure: ((<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 4) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'input_1')>,), {}), flat_sequence: [<tf.Tensor 'model/Cast:0' shape=(None, 4) dtype=float32>, True].
```

How can this be fixed/worked around?

(When using `node.call_kwargs["training"] = False` instead of `del node.call_kwargs["training"]` then `model.predict` does not crash, but it simply behaves as if nothing was changed, i.e., the modified flag is ignored.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found simply saving and re-loading the model again after modifying the `call_kwargs` helps.

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('model.h5')

# Removing training=True
for layer in model.layers:
    for node in layer.inbound_nodes:
        if "training" in node.call_kwargs:
            del node.call_kwargs["training"]

# The two following lines are the solution.
model.save('model_modified.h5', include_optimizer=False)
model = load_model('model_modified.h5')

model.predict(np.asarray([[1, 2, 3, 4]]))
```

And all is fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False
```

Comment: `"trainable": false` means the layer is frozen during training (helpful for fine-tuning/transfew-learning). It is independent of `"training": true`, which is about how some layer types (`Dropout`/`BatchNormalization`) behave. Here is an example, showing the autonomy of these two things: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/d9a8a24f22e1acc2db8fa1de757cfe9d